# jQuery inside html body

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a little project and it involves displaying a news feed. That news feed is cycled with a PHP loop but that doesn't really matter. The area that I'm having an issue with is the html and the jquery messing it all up. The html is set up like this. And it works perfect fine by itself:

```
<div class="popup">
<div class="title">
    <a href="#" style="margin:0"><img src="" /></a>
    <a href="#"><?php echo $name; ?> &middot;</a>
    <div id="form">
        <form>
            <input type="hidden" name="event" value="123" />
            <input type="submit" name="reply" class="button" value="Respond" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

There's nothing fancy about the css either. The title class just has some padding and the links are floated to the left. That's why there is a class that clears them at the end.

There is one technicality though. The div title is within a jquery popup box. So when a user clicks on another link the popup div gets displayed. Normally this popup is hidden from view.

I want to use ajax with that form in my html. So I was beginning to build the form and added this code right after the closing div tag for the div id, 'form'.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {  
      $(".button").click(function() {  
            //More  
      });  
    });  
</script>
```

As soon as I put that code in there, everything gets messed up. The popup div is displayed when it shouldn't be. I can't figure out the reason why this is happening. Is it normal with jQuery? Has anyone ever had this problem? Any suggestions?

Thank you

**Edit**

The complete html that doesn't work

```
<div id="popup" class="popup">  
<div class="popup-feed">
    <div class="feed-box">
        <div class="feed-box-title">
            <a href="#" style="margin:0"><img src="#" /></a>
            <a href="#">Alex &middot;</a>

            <div id="contact_form">
                <form>
                    <input type="hidden" name="event" value="<?php echo $status["id"]; ?>" />
                    <input type="submit" name="rsvp<?php echo $staus["id"]; ?>" value="<?php echo $rsvpStatus; ?>" />
                </form>
            </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {  
      $(".button").click(function() {  
            //More  
      });  
    });  
</script>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="feed-content">
            <?php /*Content*/ ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div><script type="text/javascript">$(function () { $('#popup').modalPopLite({ openButton: '#1', closeButton: '#close', isModal: false }); }); </script>
```

The javascript for it http://alexkonetchy.com/example/modalPopLite.php and http://alexkonetchy.com/example/popup.php

The css http://alexkonetchy.com/example/popup.css

Note none of that javascript or css code is mine

Comment: Show me your javascript imports

Comment: *"Any suggestions?"* Well... something must be wrong with your code. jQuery does only what you tell it to do. The information you provided is not sufficient to help you further though. *" Is it normal with jQuery?"* I'd say no.

Comment: Sorry I was hoping that would be enough information. The popup is pretty complicated and I didn't want to provide too much code. I'll edit it real quick

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo. Only post what is relevant. The JavaScript code you posted so far does not contain anything special. All it does is binding an event handler, and this won't have any affect on the visibility of elements.

Comment: Shall I assume you have loaded [jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) correctly? Anyhow, you can check your browser's error console to get insight of what's happening underneath...

Comment: I did load it correctly. Because jquery scripts work on the page without it. I'm not a javascript expert at all though. Just copy and paste scripts, but I'm assuming that it's the popup script that is making it break. Its too complicated of a question for here though, so I'll hack away at it and post small questions if I have them.

Comment: @FelixKling I did post the complete code. Although I don't know if it helps much. If you do figure it out let me know. If it's too complicated don't worry about it, I'll work on trying to fix the problem myself. I suspect the problem has to be in the popup.js file.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a small fiddle demo for you. You have to prevent the default button click event.

```
$(function() {  
      $(".button").on('click', function(event) {  
            //More  
          alert('Your Ajax goes here');
          event.preventDefault();
      });  
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K3fxq/