# Why my Javascript input validation doesn't want to run?

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in javascript so I already have some issues at the beginning. It is about input validation where for some reason my alert function doesn't want to run.

Here is HTML code or input section:

```js
const txtName = document.querySelector("#name");
const btnNotify = document.querySelector("#btn-notify");
const msgText = document.querySelector("#.text");
const msgTexttwo = document.querySelector("#.texttwo")
const mailFormat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;


btnNotify.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(txtName.value.match(mailFormat)  ) {
        msgText.classList.add('hide');
        msgTexttwo.classList.add('hide');
        txtName.removeAttribute('style')
    
    }else {
        msgText.classList.add('hide');
        msgTexttwo.classList.add('hide');
        txtName.setAttribute('style', 'border: 2px solid red;');
    }


});
```

```html
<div class="input">
    <input id="name" class="error" type="email" placeholder="Your email address...">
    <span class="text hide">Please provide valid email address</span>
    <span class="texttwo hide">Please provide valid email address</span>
    <a id="btn-notify" class="click" href="">Notify Me</a>
</div>
```

Comment: See the console message

Comment: You probably also have to [prevent the default action of the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601979/jquery-inside-html-body), otherwise the page gets refreshed.

Comment: Typos remove the hash `const msgTexttwo = document.querySelector("#.texttwo")`

Comment: `btnNotify.addEventListener('click', (e) => { e,preventDefault(); ...`

Answer (score 0):

to get a class you have to use '.' and '#' for id
you are using both of them
const msgText = document.querySelector("#.text");
const msgTexttwo = document.querySelector("#.texttwo")

here is a correction of your code

```js
const txtName = document.querySelector("#name");
const btnNotify = document.querySelector("#btn-notify");
const msgText = document.querySelector(".text");
const msgTexttwo = document.querySelector(".texttwo")
const mailFormat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;


btnNotify.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(txtName.value.match(mailFormat)  ) {
        msgText.classList.add('hide');
        msgTexttwo.classList.add('hide');
        txtName.removeAttribute('style')
    
    }else {
        msgText.classList.add('hide');
        msgTexttwo.classList.add('hide');
        txtName.setAttribute('style', 'border: 2px solid red;');
    }


});
```

```html
<div class="input">
    <input id="name" class="error" type="email" placeholder="Your email address...">
    <span class="text hide">Please provide valid email address</span>
    <span class="texttwo hide">Please provide valid email address</span>
    <a id="btn-notify" class="click" href="#">Notify Me</a>
</div>
```